# What is R table function max size?

Tags: r

I'm using the R table() function, it only gives me 4222 rows, is there some kind of configuration to accept more rows?

Comment: can you please provide a reproducible example: http://gist.github.com/270442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`table` function is not limited to 4222 rows. Most likely, it is the printing limit that gives you the trouble.

Try:

```
options(max.print = 20000)
```

also, check the "real" number of rows:

```
tbl <- table(state.division, state.region)
nrow(tbl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with larger tables? What gave you that impression?

```
> set.seed(123)
> fac <- factor(sample(10000, 10000, rep = TRUE))
> fac2 <- factor(sample(10000, 10000, rep = TRUE))
> tab <- table(fac, fac2)
> str(tab)
 'table' int [1:6282, 1:6279] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ fac : chr [1:6282] "1" "5" "7" "9" ...
  ..$ fac2: chr [1:6279] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

Printing `tab` will cause problems - it takes a while to generate and then you'll get this message:

```
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 6267 rows ]]
```

You can alter that by changing `options(max.print = XXXXX)` where `XXXXX` is some large number. But I don't see what is gained by printing such a large table? If you were trying to do this to see if the correct table had been produced, size-wise, then

```
> dim(tab)
[1] 6282 6279
> str(tab)
 'table' int [1:6282, 1:6279] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ fac : chr [1:6282] "1" "5" "7" "9" ...
  ..$ fac2: chr [1:6279] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
```

help with that.

Comment: Thanks I realise from the earlier answer that I had to set the maxprint option

Comment: @Jayanth; yep, VitoshKa and I seem to have been composing our answers at the same time.